# TimedJSONWebSignatureSerializer is not found

Tags: python, flask

I am using itsdangerous 2.1.2 and when I attempt to import TimedJSONWebSignatureSerializer PyCharm does not seem to like it.  When I type Timed on the dropdown list, I only get TimedSerializer and URLSafeTimedSerializer.  Has this package changed names?

My goal is to build a random url for file upload.

[image]

Comment: Take a look at the changelog for this package - [link](https://itsdangerous.palletsprojects.com/en/2.1.x/changes/). The JWS (`JSONWebSignatureSerializer`, `TimedJSONWebSignatureSerializer`) support has been deprecated from v2.0.0 onwards

Answer (score 0):

this class had been expired.they said you can use other json-wen-token library instead.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).